# SQL Server Multiple Counts in the same Query - CosmosDB

Tags: sql

I want to create a query counting the total number of liks and dislikes within a collection of documents described below.

```
{
    "id": "403031b7-a1b6-4e08-9d82-360bb41b97cd",
    "car_id": "0839404d5bc4140f28abfd19329b0ebc",
    "created": 1621881785,
    "type": "like",
    "version": 1,
    "fingerprint": "kHqPGWS1Mj18sZFsP8Wl",
}

{
    "id": "403031b7-a1b6-4e08-9d82-360bb41b97cd",
    "car_id": "0839404d5bc4140f28abfd19329b0ebc",
    "created": 1621881785,
    "type": "unlike",
    "version": 1,
    "fingerprint": "kHqPGWS1Mj18sZFsP8Wl",
}
```

---

The following works perfect for one count:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS likes from cars c WHERE c.type="like" and c.car_id="0839404d5bc4140f28abfd19329b0ebc"
```

But I want to count booth likes and unlikes where c.type is "like" and c.type="unlike" in the same query.

---

Resulting in something like this:

```
{
    "likes": a,
    "unlikes": b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS likes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.type = 'unlike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unlikes
FROM cars c
WHERE c.car_id = '0839404d5bc4140f28abfd19329b0ebc';
```

Or use aggregation:

```
select c.type, count(*)
from cars c
where c.car_id = '0839404d5bc4140f28abfd19329b0ebc'
group by c.type;
```

Comment: Huge tanks for your assistance!

I don't get the first example working though, seems like Cosmos DB left out CASE in their implementation.

Comment: @AntonA . . . I wonder why some vendors call a language SQL.  Sigh.